# FormCloseQuery equivalent in MFC

Tags: mfc

In Delphi, there is FormCloseQuery event. What is equivalent in MFC?

I want to stop CMainFrame from closing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add a handler to the **WM_CLOSE** message in your CMainFrame Message Map:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMainFrame, CFrameWnd)
    ...
    ON_WM_CLOSE()
    ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

2) Add **afx_msg void OnClose();** to class definition in the header file

3) Add **CMainFrame::OnClose()** implementation

```
void CMainFrame::OnClose()
{
    if (okToClose)
    {
        CFrameWnd::OnClose();
    }
    else
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```